# Bulk Updating from Collection

Tags: apex

I have two objects O1 & O2

I have the following map populated.

```
Map<O1.Name, O2.Id>
```

My objective is to update a field O1.FK_Id with O2.id

Can someone suggest me a simple method to handle this in bulk ?

Comment: can you please paste your code here

Comment: I think better to populate a map with the two objects like `Map<01,02>` and maintain a list of `02` and perform the update

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set `O1.FK_Id = O2.id` in the same spot you are populating the map? You would have a reference to both O1 and O2 at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get set of keys from the map. -> keys
2. Select all O1 objects where name = :keys -> O1list
3. Iterate over all O1list and update every item with O2.id taken from map: item.FK_id = map.get(item.name)
4. update 01list